# React Material UI - How to centre contents to the middle of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

At the moment, the button is outputting on the top left corner. How to bring the button to the middle of the page?

```
import {Button} from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  return (
      <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Tried the above code but obviously requires more changes to centre it

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, which way do you prefer?

Comment: Using React / Material UI way if possible..

Comment: Might be useful: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Grid, if you don't want to add custom styles

```
import { Button, Grid } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Still at the top row centre, and not in middle centre :(

Comment: You can set Grid height to 100vh

Comment: Thanks, 100vh worked - button now in middle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Box` tag:

```
<Box textAlign='center'>
  <Button variant='contained'>
     Hello World
  </Button>
</Box>
```

Comment: Thanks, this brings the button to the centre of the top row. How to move it to the middle centre?

Comment: Then you should add styles to your button and the parent tag. The position of the parent tag should be relative and the button absolute, then you can add top, left attributes to fix it the way you want.